# How to use admin.auth().createUser() with hashed password on Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, hash, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a web app using Angular for the frontend and Cloud Functions for backend stuff. Also using Firebase Authentication to register and login users. To persist data I'm using Cloud Firestore.

The register part is used on Cloud Functions. There I call admin.auth().createUser() to set the user credentials for the Auth user as well as for the user document that I add to Cloud Firestore.

My problem is that I hash the password value on the frontend before the HTTP request to Functions is sent. I do this because of safety reasons. But how can I revert the hash, so I can write the raw password into createUser()?

Actually I save the hashed password and after that I can't login with the created user, because it's the hashed value.

My function in Cloud Functions:

```
exports.createUser = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const user = req.body;
        console.log(user.password);
        const userRecord = await admin.auth().createUser({
            email: user.mail,
            emailVerified: false,
            password: user.password,
            displayName: user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname,
            photoURL: "http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png",
            disabled: false
        }).then(async (userRecord) => {
            console.log(userRecord.password);
            console.log(userRecord);
            return  await userCollection.doc(userRecord.uid).set({
                uid: userRecord.uid,
                firstname: user.firstname,
                lastname: user.lastname,
                photoURL: userRecord.photoURL,
                dateOfBirth: user.dateOfBirth,
                sex: user.sex,
                city: user.city,
                activities: user.activities,
                offers: user.offers
            })
          })
          console.log("Successfully created new user:");
          return res.status(200).send(userRecord);    
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
            return res.send(false);
    }
```

The hashing on the frontend looks like this (using ts-md5):

```
 password: Md5.hashStr(this.registerForm.value.registerFormPassword)
```

Is there a method to reverse the hash or a method from Firebase Auth to hash the password on the client side and a counterpart to revert it on the server side?

I searched the internet for answers but can't find anything to this topic, so could it be that this is absolutely the wrong way with hashing the password? And if so, what's good practise in such cases?

Comment: You don't really need to hash on the client side. If you are using an SSL connection, it should be good enough. The data will be encrypted in flight.